# Add variable to end of url or dynamically ajax reload tab

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dynamic

This is a little hard for me to explain as i am not much of a coder. So here we go.

I have script that is mostly encoded with ion cube. Not i have an addon that is also encoded. The addon is loading in a tab number 5. The problem is that every time i click on a function in the tab that complete page reloads, and you have to navigate back to tab 5 to see the results.

So this is what i am thinking. As i can't edit code and the make of the code doesn't know when they are adding tab support to their little piece of code. i figured that there are two options

1 Force the following variable to the end of the url #tab5 so that when people click a function they will not have to navigate back to the tab. How do i do this coding wise, javascript or something else and what would code be or where would i look to code something like that. I have looked everywhere but nothing really applies to my situation

2 I think it would also work if each function which is called just reloads that section of the page in an ajax field so that not the full page is being reloaded.

Who can help find the right solution.

thanks

Comment: use datatable https://datatables.net/

Comment: Well as you wont be able to show code (because of ioncube), then i suggest you provide a link. The solution could be as simple 2 lines of javascript, but without more details its no point guessing

Comment: well that is a bit of a problem because it is in members area of the script whmcs

Comment: well that is a bit of a problem because it is in members area of the script whmcs. this is the module http://www.cnukhosting.com/digital-ocean-whmcs-module/

this module is being loaded in a tab. The code is as followed 

<div data-toggle="tab" id="tab5" class="tab-content">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col30">
            <div class="internalpadding">
                <div class="styled_title"><h2>{$LANG.serverinformation}</h2></div>
                <p>{$LANG.servercontrolintro}</p>
                <br />
There is more but not really important.